# How pass a login form with CYPRESS?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I manage to run CYPRESS without any worries on a site without authentication.

But on an intranet, I can't identify myself. I must to log in before.

Here is my code:

```js
describe('home', () => {
  it('home accessible', () => {
    cy.visit('/') 
  })

  //We fill the login FORM
  it('User Field', () => {
    cy.get('input#user') 
      .type('login') 
    })    
  it('User pass', () => {
    cy.get('input#pass')  
      .type('mot de passe') 
    })    
      it('check consent', () => {
     cy.get('input#permalogin') 
      .click({ force: true }) 
     })  
     it('submit', () => {
    cy.get('input.btn.btn-primary')     
      .click()               
  })

  //the form is submit, we can visit a page
    it('autre page!!', () => {
    cy.visit('/luniversite/page-2',{ timeout: 30000 })    
  })
  //We check the title of the page, we should be on the page 2
  it('titre  page 2', () => {
    cy.title().should('eq', 'page 2: INTRANET)       
  })
```

CYPRESS and the CYPRESS video show me that I am blocked on the authentication page.
The test on the title of the page is not correct, I don't access page-2. I stay on the first page for log in.

Answer (score 2):

First thing's first: This appears to be one test, but you are specifying multiple it() functions, which is breaking it up into multiple tests, which is not what you want. You will want to restructure your test like this:

```
describe("home", () => {
  it("home accessible", () => {
    cy.visit("/");
    //We fill the login FORM
    cy.get("input#user").type("login");
    cy.get("input#pass").type("mot de passe");
    cy.get("input#permalogin").click({ force: true });    
    cy.get("input.btn.btn-primary").click();
    cy.visit("/luniversite/page-2", { timeout: 30000 });
    cy.title().should("eq", "page 2: INTRANET");
  });
});
```

With that out of the way, it's hard to know what your application is doing without more details:

1/ When executed manually, is your application authenticating properly with the provided credentials? Do you have console errors? Have you determined that the element locators you're using are actually interacting with the elements in the manner you expect?

2/ Is your test attempting to navigate to `/luniversite/page-2` before authentication is complete? If so, you may want to use intercept your authentication call and wait for it to complete:

```
// get your authentication POST request from network tab of devtools and use that in the cy.intercept call    
cy.intercept('POST', '/yourAuthenticationCallUrl').as("@authenticationCall")
// YOUR LOGIN STEPS HERE
cy.wait("@authenticationCall") //waits for the authentication call to complete before moving to the next step
cy.visit("/luniversite/page-2", { timeout: 30000 });
```